# No Rule To Make libcamera_client_intermedietes

Tags: android, linux, android-source

I'm getting error while compiling in OmniROM 5.1. I already had the libcamera_client.so in the out directory, already removed couple of things on BoardConfig. (USE_CAMERA_STUB and HEAP sizes.)

Error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/taco/android/omni/out/target  /product/m1/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcamera_client_intermediates/export_includes', needed by '/home/taco/android/omni/out/target/product/m1/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_runtime_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.
```

make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Copying: /home/taco/android/omni/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.android.vcard_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar

Answer (score 0):

for some reason your build system does not compile:
frameworks/av/camera/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_MODULE:= libcamera_client
```

So either you dont have **libcamera_client** in your product packages or the Android.mk somehow no not getting loaded.